# Is there an Excel VBA function for checking whether another Excel file is actively saving?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there VBA code I can use to check whether an Excel file is actively being saved?

I'm using a VBA macro in an Excel file (File A) to open another Excel file (File B).

```
DummyDirectory="C:\DummyFolder1\DummyFolder2\"

Workbooks.Open filename:=DummyDirectory & "DummyFile.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True
```

If File B is actively being saved by someone else, when I run the macro in File A, I receive a run-time error (1004). I would like to check whether File B is actively being saved by someone else before attempting to open File B with my macro in File A.

I'd prefer to not use error handling based on run-time error 1004, since this error can occur for other reasons.

Comment: This check is pointless, because someone might start actively saving the file right after your check tells you it's not being saved. You have to handle the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't.

Indeed, error 1004 can happen for a wide variety of reasons. However here:

```
Workbooks.Open filename:=DummyDirectory & "DummyFile.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True
```

Assuming the `filename` argument is legal, then error 1004 being thrown by that line means "Excel wasn't able to save the file" - you don't get to see the actual reason for this, because the "file is currently write-locked by another user" error is caught by Excel, handled, wrapped, and presented to VBA as an ever so helpful "application-defined error".

Truth is, the actual error *doesn't matter at all* - all VBA needs to know is that `Workbooks.Open` failed.

Handle the error, *and limit the scope of your error handling as much as possible*. One way to do this is to put the instruction in its own function (aircode, untested):

```
Public Function TryOpenWorkbookReadOnly(ByVal filename As String, ByRef outBook As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set outBook = Workbooks.Open filename, ReadOnly:=True
    On Error GoTo 0
    TryOpenWorkbookReadOnly = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

And now you can use standard control flow:

```
Dim book As Workbook
If Not TryOpenWorkbookReadOnly(DummyDirectory & "DummyFile.xlsb", outBook:=book) Then
    MsgBox "Could not open the file. Try again later."
    Exit Sub
End If

'go on, use the book object as needed:
'...
```